# Repetition of terms due to \cancel error

Tags: math-mode, errors, cancel

I'm writing the following equations

```
\[k_f^\dagger k_f = M_f U_f^\dagger (y_f ^\dagger)^{-1}(y_f)^{-1}U_f M_f = M_f \cancel{U_f^\dagger} \cancel{(U_f^\dagger)^{-1}}(M_f^2)^{-1}\cancel{U_f^{-1}}\cancel{U_f}M_f =\mathbbm{1}\]
```

the terms canceled with `\cancel{}` command, however, after compiling with LuaLaTex, are doubled and made smaller [image]
I don't know what causes the error. This is the list of packages I'm using
(some may be repeated). 
EDIT: it seems there occurs some problem with the package `breqn`. I'm wondering if anyone knows the cause. Actually I **really** need the `breqn` package since I'm dealing with long equations. You can test this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} 
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\[\cancel{A}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: I removed the package `breqn` but I keep having errors using for example split or aligned `! Missing { inserted.<to be read again>\def \end{split}` while with `breqn` there was no error. However in a minimal new worksheet everything wors fine.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please make a full (but minimal) example that others can copy and test as is.

Comment: the problem is that if I make a minimal example the cancel package works: there must be some issue with other package and  i don't know which one

Comment: @daleif i made the minimal example realizing the breqn package is the cause, but don't know why

Comment: `breqn` has to change the entire math setup so it is incompatible with most packages. In general it is recommended not to use `breqn`

Comment: which package may I use to break long equations? I use the `\begin{aligned}` and then break equations with `&` and `\\ `\` but I think without `breqn` it doesn't work..

Comment: I can only reproduce the issue by running `lualatex` from TeX Live 2015. I guess your TeX distribution is quite outdated.

Comment: Load amsmath and aligned and align works just fine

Comment: @egreg are you sure? i just updated texlive and the error persists. Now I run Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)

Comment: @daleif `aligned` doesn't work the same without `breqn` to me..I get some compiling errors after removing the package `breqn`

Comment: @alelenoci That's suspiciously near to the one I got problem with.

Comment: how can i further update my tex? On ubuntu I've simply typed sudo apt-get install texlive and it told me what to update. Is there any repository where to update?

Comment: Please update your question, so we can see the mwe you are working with now. It is also a good idea to cite the error you get. Remember, aligned should not be used on its own. Did you remember to load the amsmath package instead of breqn?

Comment: the error is `! Missing { inserted.<to be read again>\def \end{split}`.I had amsmath loaded of course. Now in the minimal new sheet I get no errors but in the old full sheet when I remove `breqn` the error appears.

Comment: Then add the new mwe so we can see it an possibly test it

Comment: I had problems with the tikz-feynman package, now I solved it.  Thank you for suggesting removing breqn. What should I do with the question now?